# How to set path to a component image using style jsx tag in nextjs

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, next.js

I am using jsx to define styles for the `NextJs` components and i need to define a background image for some elements.

The only paths that seems to accept is the relative path, to the current page, or absolute path. 
But how to pass a relative path to the component itself?

Here a simple component function for testing:

```
import React from 'react'

const  TestComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
        <h1 className="test">See my background</h1>
        <style jsx>{`
        .test {
            background-image: url("someImageFile.jpg");
        }
        `}</style>
        </div>
    )
}
export default  TestComponent
```

This will return the 404 error for url "localhost:3000/current page/someImageFile.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

For a `NextJS` application, you should have a `public` folder at the root of the directory of your app where you store all the `static` files: such as images.

Here is a link to the official documentation where they explain it very clearly:

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: That is an way to do it, but i want to keep images files within the component folder, as posted.

Comment: You can't. As NextJS is server side rendered, it needs to have the statics of the project in that folder. Always trust what the documentation tells you.

Comment: It should have a way to encapsulate it.  And it has several ways to do it, with style jsx too..

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `$` to be able to call `require` function:

```
<style jsx>{`
      .test{
        background-image: url(${require("./someImageFile.jpg")});
      }         
`}</style>
```

Reference documentation [here](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#server-side-rendering).